# How do I get the id from an ObjectID, using Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to get the id from the document which I have in MongoDB, using PyMongo.

Here is my code:

```
docQuery = db.doctors.find({"email":doc_mail})
doc_id = docQuery[0]["_id"]["$oid"]
```

I have tried this too:

```
 doc_id = docQuery[0]["_id"]
```

Neither of them works!

Comment: You really should start with the official tutorial: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html

Comment: I did that.
They have given a way to get a doc if its id is known,but i dint get to know a way to find the id if the obect is given.the above method(2nd one) works for all the attributes except id!

Comment: Use the [**`find_one()`**](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.find_one) method `doc_id = db.doctors.find_one({"email":doc_mail})["_id"]`

Comment: @chridam Assuming the condition is found in the collection.

Comment: Okay.
I have tried this too "print docQuery.cursor_id"
it dint work too!!

Comment: @user3425344 did the solution help you? let me know please.

Comment: @salmanwahed sure.Il tell you in a minute.Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Though your second approach should work, `docQuery` is a `Cursor` type object. Best way is to iterate over it like:

```
for itm in db.doctors.find({"email":doc_mail}):
   print itm.get('_id')
```

Or if there is only one object, then use `find_one` like:

```
itm = db.doctors.find_one({"email":doc_mail})
print itm.get('_id')
```

Answer (score 2):

In pymongo you can use [''] this notation to access the specific property. 

Example -

```
cursor = collection.find({})
for document in cursor:
        print document['_id']
```